# A simple jQuery on click function to remove an attribute

Tags: python, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Its a simple button when clicked removes an attribute (disabled).

My input tag:

```
<input id="password" disabled="disabled" value="************" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control">
```

My button:

```
<button id="edit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>
```

I have tried using a few methods:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edit_button").click(function(){            
        $("password").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
```

Second

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bedit_button").click(function(){            
        $("#password").prop('disabled',false);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#bedit_button").` typo

Comment: `$("password")`  Missing the `#` for the id, so another typo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7cdsauLj/ works for me.

Comment: @ruohola you fixed both the typos, so of course it does

Comment: @Taplar so did he fix them in his question. That would let others assume that the issue was not those, but it was.

Comment: the typos arent the problem, there arent any typos in the actual code.

Comment: @iNoob A question should not be updated to include the fix for the problem.  I've reverted it back to the version that demonstrated the typos.

Comment: I worked out the problem, its a flask application and the script wasnt loading. I have added it to the main rather than extended template and it is now working,

Comment: In that case I am voting to reopen, to allow the author to post an answer of how they fixed the issue themselves.

Comment: Please post the fix to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this application is written in Flask which uses Jinja2 templates. The jquery was not being picked up in the extension so once placing it in the base.html it worked fine. Thanks for the help non the less.